# How to read a local image file and encode with base64 string before invoke in PostMan

Tags: postman, grpc

I have a gRPC service to test in PostMan. The method in the service need a base64 encoded image string and its length as a parameter. So I try to do it in the scripts before invoke the gRPC method. How to read the image file in the local computer and encode the file into base64 string and compute its length, and then pass the two variables into the gRPC message to invoke the method.